# Is the HttpContext.Current.Cache available to all sessions

Tags: asp.net, caching

As per title.  I want to be able to save some data in a cache object but this object must be available to all users/sessions and can expire.

What is the best method to achieve this in a asp.net web app?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

[`HttpContext.Current`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.current.aspx) is available to all *pages*, but not necessarily to all threads.  If you try to use it inside a background thread, [`ThreadPool`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.aspx) delegate, async call (using an ASP.NET Async page), etc., you'll end up with a [`NullReferenceException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.nullreferenceexception.aspx).

If you need to get access to the cache from library classes, i.e. classes that don't have knowledge of the current request, you should use [`HttpRuntime.Cache`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpruntime.cache.aspx) instead.  This is more reliable because it doesn't depend on an [`HttpContext`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.aspx).

Comment: @Aaronnaught - I'm not sure how there is a difference beyond access to HttpContext.Current since HttpContext.Current.Cache returns HttpRuntime.Cache.

Comment: @Aaronnaught - I suppose you are saying that not having to depend on HttpContext.Current is in fact that advantage?

Comment: @Thomas: `HttpContext.Current.Cache` just points to the same cache as `HttpRuntime.Cache` anyway, but the former introduces an intermediate dependency that has the potential to break something later.  Search for "HttpContext NullReferenceException" here on SO and you'll see what I mean...

Comment: Hmm. Ok. I've never encountered an error referencing HttpContext.Current, but given what I've read, I'll buy that HttpRuntime.Cache would be a better choice. +1.

Answer (score 5):

*HttpContext.Current.Cache* will be present, but Current should only be used if you cant get to your context member.

Also to answer your second question, yes, the *Cache* object is global to the application.

Here's a good intro to caching...

[How to cache in ASP.NET by using Visual C# .NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/323290)

and...

[Caching with ASP.NET](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020113508/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/022802-1.aspx) .  Don't skip part 2, "Data Caching"

Comment: 4GuysFromRolla - wow thats a blast from the past :-).  Has there really been no changes to caching in ASP.Net since 2002?